# Centering a navigation bar title (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, nslayoutconstraint

I'm programming a little app and I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to solve it. The problem is that for phones (like iPhone7) with a smaller width of the screen size **the title appears uncentered**.

The following image shows a capture of the problem when the app is executed in a iPhone7.

[image]

I think that the problem is that there is no such space on the right to center the title.

To solve that I tried to move the 2 icons on the right to the right as the following image shows:

[image]

But, altough the lines icon is moved to the right the title is still uncentered as the following capture shows:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to solve it without having to delete one of the two icons on the right.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you constraining everything in the Nav Bar yourself or are you using the nav bar properties to create this layout?

Comment: @MAT I'm using the nav bar propierties

Comment: You can add an empty button or with alpha set to zero to the left side to even out the margins. If you end up setting alpha to zero, make sure you set isHitTestVisible to false.

Comment: @elliott-io Already tried, the title truncates as there is not such space to display it

Comment: Well, there is only so much space on the screen. Maybe change your text for smaller screens to "BDAY" or something.

Comment: @elliott-io I will do so if I don't find the way to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding them programmatically? The end result should be an array of these two buttons as such: `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [lineButton, otherButton]`. Make sure `image inset` is set back to its original values.

Comment: I have tried it but adding them progrmmatically doesn't change anything of its arrengement